# In woocommerce how to add Participant List on checkout page and show in order detail page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

How to add list of participant in check out and show in order detail page. using function and wordpress action and filters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add field after order notes field in checkout page. 
add below code in function.php to get below screen. Here we show total item in cart -1 rows. Because 1 participant is that make order.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );

function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
global $woocommerce;

$class_basket_count = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
$class_basket_count = $class_basket_count - 1;
if($class_basket_count >= 1){
    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h3>' . __('Participant List') . '</h3>';
    for ($i=1; $i <= $class_basket_count; $i++ ){

        woocommerce_form_field( 'guest-name-'.$i, array(
            'type'          => 'text',
            'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Guest Name'),
            'placeholder'   => __('Enter Name'),
            ), $checkout->get_value( 'guest-name-'.$i ));

        woocommerce_form_field( 'guest-email-'.$i, array(
            'type'          => 'text',
            'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Guest Email'),
            'placeholder'   => __('Enter Email'),
            ), $checkout->get_value( 'guest-email-'.$i ));
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
}
```

---

To add and update meta value of Participant List. Add below code in function.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
global $woocommerce;
$class_basket_count = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
for ($i=1; $i <= $class_basket_count; $i++ ){
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['guest-name-'.$i] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'guest-name-'.$i, sanitize_text_field( $_POST['guest-name-'.$i] ) );
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'guest-email-'.$i, sanitize_text_field( $_POST['guest-email-'.$i] ) );
    }

}
}
```

---

To show list in order detail page. See screen short.
[image]

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
$totla_class_ordered = $order->get_item_count();
echo '<h4>Participant Details</h4>';
echo '<div class="participant-details"><table>';
echo '<thead><tr><th>Guest Name</th><th>Guest Email</th></tr></thead>';

for ($i=1; $i <= $totla_class_ordered; $i++ ){
    echo '<tr><td>'.get_post_meta( $order->id, 'guest-name-'.$i, true ) . '</td><td>'.get_post_meta( $order->id, 'guest-email-'.$i, true ) . '</td>';
}
echo '</table></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And for adding participant list to emails sent: (maybe helpfull to someone)

```
add_action('woocommerce_email_customer_details','add_list_to_emails', 15, 4 );

function add_verification_id_to_emails_notifications( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {

global $woocommerce;
$total_class_ordered = $order->get_item_count();
if ($total_class_ordered > 1) {

    echo '<h3>Details of extra participants</h3>';
    echo '<div class="participant-details" style="margin-top: 10px;"><table>';
    echo '<thead><tr><th style="text-align: left;">Name</th><th style="text-align: left;">Email</th></tr></thead>';

    for ( $i = 1; $i <= $total_class_ordered; $i ++ ) {
        echo '<tr><td>' . get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'guest-name-' . $i, true ) .
             '</td><td>' . get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'guest-email-' . $i, true ) .

             '</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</table></div>';
}
```

}